# What's a more persistent alternative to tooltips?

Tags: tooltips, hidden, visibility

I'm designing a dashboard that includes some jargon that is not yet commonly known in the client's industry. This includes terms that would need to give further details about how certain calculations are in the dashboard.

The most common way of handling this issue might be simply using a tool tip next to the word itself. However, tooltips are known to have their own issues and could be missed.

**My question is what's a better way to show the meaning of the words used in the dashboard without hiding them behind a click?** A popup might be a solution but once it's dismissed it needs to be able to be accessed again quite easily.

[image: application has filters, insights, and charts]

Comment: Can you explain what the graphic is supposed to show us?

Answer (score 1):

There's a concept pretty common in complex web apps, of an icon that encourages you to hover on it and get a tooltip. Typically it will be a question mark, like here in Google Analytics:

[image]

I've heard it referred to as "clicktip", but I'm not sure how universal this term is. And it usually refers to icons that you need to click rather than hover, but that's a matter of decision. You can get it to behave like a tooltip (which Google Analytics did) in that it disappears by itself after a couple seconds. Or you can make it more persistent and wait for the next mouse click to disappear. The main point is that it's visible and encourages users to ask for the information.

An alternative is Wikipedia's way of underlining certain words and then showing you the excerpts of their wiki pages on hover.

[image]

The problem with this of course is that they look like hyperlinks, and you may not want to confuse the two. Then you can employ other typographic means to highlight the "meaningful" terms. This from Collins dictionary:
[image]

If you're worried about the tooltip needing to be explicitly accessed again once it's gone, I think that the alternative is to keep a dedicated area on your screen for these explanations. This was common a couple decades ago but it proved to be a very bad idea (it was usually in a remote location on the screen so as not to interfere with the main content, and the user had to move their eyes all the way across the screen, and I think that it disappeared when tooltips became more standard.

An even worse alternative is to keep the tooltips open until manually dismissed, that just messes up all your content.

Answer (score 1):

That would probably be "Microcopy" (small text below element to explain meaning) or some sort of "Legend" (small numbers next to elements, explained at the bottom with small text). 
If it will take much space you could also allow user to hide it.

Comment: Thanks xul. Have you got any examples that show this?

Comment: Nope, but Google does. Both of the UI elements are often used in different scenarios, similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether the platform you are using in custom built, or on Tableau/ Power BI. You might be a bit limited in the latter.

- But if it is the former - maybe including a small 'How to use this graph' link could open a modal with instructions, or could trigger a mini onboarding tutorial. This is a lot of work though.
- The other option like you said is popover tips.
- Another option is to have a side panel with descriptions up top, and maybe make it collapsible to prevent information overload for people who become familiar with using it.